# Perform Segue After Alert

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

This is the what I am using to get the text from an alert and check for matching data:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString *passcode = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        //Logic to check match
        //...
        //...
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushMCQView" sender:sender];
    }
}
```

I do not understand what I need to pass as the `sender` in the call. I have tried `self` and `alertView`, and both times the application crashes. If someone could please explain the role of `sender`, and what would work in my case, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to pas "nil" in sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString *passcode = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        //Logic to check match
        //...
        //...
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushMCQView" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Sender is the reference from where the action is performing. Like in `- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender` here sender is the button. You can even cast the sender as a UIButton. Hope this helps.. :)